# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application while automating through Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Code block:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Cypher/Downloads/chromedriver_win32.zip')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://www.google.com/gmail/')
email_field = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
email_field.clear()
email_field.send_keys('My mail')
email_next_button = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
email_next_button.click()
time.sleep(1)
password_field = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password_field.clear()
password_field.send_keys('My password')
password_next_button = browser.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
password_next_button.click()
time.sleep(100)
browser.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cypher/PycharmProjects/untitled5/login_gmail.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Cypher/Downloads/chromedriver_win32.zip')
  File "C:\Users\Cypher\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Cypher\PycharmProjects\untitled5\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Cypher\Miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Cypher\Miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: You may want to add more details to the question like what you want to achieve and what else have you tried to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the chromedriver you have downloaded... `chromedriver_win32.zip` make sure you have the `chromedriver.exe` file in the downloads...

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Cypher/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

...implies that the *argument* which you have passed to initialize *Chrome* was not in the valid format.

You need to consider a couple of facts as follows:

- When you simply pass the *absolute location* of the *ChromeDriver* by default it is considered as the *Value* for the *argument* **executable_path** which accepts a value of an **executable binary**
- As you are on *Windows OS* you need to extract the *chromedriver.exe* from **chromedriver_win32.zip** and place it anywhere within your system.
- Next you need to pass the *absolute location* of the *chromedriver.exe* along with the *argument* **executable_path**.
- The *argument* `executable_path` must be supported with a *Value* as either of the following:

  - `r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe'`
  - `"C:/python/chromedriver.exe"`
  - `"C:\\python\\chromedriver.exe"`
- The working line of code will be:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Comment: Good idea to add all the options of the path... :)